# How to get a column value repeated to all related rows of a data table?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Table with a header 'EXP' column date values`]

The table has EXPIRY date column, and it does not repeat on all rows:
This is a Option price table for MSFT(Microsoft), the data table is sorted by Expiry date on sheet 'BACKEND'.So, when I fetch via Query function, I only get one row value for Expiry column.

How can I get column FC on all related rows to repeat the Date Label for each row?

Google sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fzNH3pAGSeazbO1sh2CeopDJqJFfxqvPyeoCnk7l0X8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it's not clear were the dates are actually stored, please share the spreadsheet or a reduced copy

Comment: what is the relationship of which you speak?

Comment: See [this fill-down formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/154715/269219). The sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." See [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).